# как сделать так чтоб div заходил на figure? так как показано на картинке

Tags: html, css3

[image: блок на фигуру]

как сделать так как на картинке, чтоб div с текстом заходил на figure ?

Comment: [Позиционирование](https://html5book.ru/css-position/)

Comment: @AlexSazonov, которое тут не требуется...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать относительное позиционирование. Необходимо добавить блоку с текстом свойство `position: relative` и сместить его вверх на необходимое количество пикселей, например на 30: `top: -30px`. Т.к. относительно спозиционированные блоки не выпадают из общего потока элементов и сохраняют за собой место которое занимали изначально, чтобы элементы, расположенные снизу блока отображались корректно и заполняли образованное свободное пространство, нужно добавить блоку отрицательный внешний отступ снизу, равный количеству заданных пикселей в свойстве top: `margin-bottom: -30px`.
Пример:

```css
.section_1 {
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}

.text_block {
  background: green;
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto;

  position: relative;
  top: -30px;
  margin-bottom: -30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="section_1"></div>
<div class="text_block">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatem beatae maiores tenetur ex dolor corrupti laboriosam dicta non necessitatibus exercitationem</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Используй отрицательный `margin-top`:

```css
body {
  background: antiquewhite;
}

figure {
  height: 4em;
  margin: 0;
  background: silver;
}

div {
  margin: -2em auto 0;
  width: 50%;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<figure></figure>
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatem beatae maiores tenetur ex dolor corrupti laboriosam dicta non necessitatibus exercitationem</div>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatem beatae maiores tenetur ex dolor corrupti laboriosam dicta non necessitatibus exercitationem
```